# Extending styled components

Tags: styled-components, formik

I have a `Field` Formik's component, in order to apply custom CSS I do:

```
const Input = styled(Field)`
  // CSS goes here
`
```

And use `Input` component, works fine. However I use exactly the same CSS in many places, so I've extracted those CSS to standalone styled-component called `SuperInput`

Now, how can extend style-componet? I need something like

```
const Input = styled(Field)`
  // inlucde CSS from SuperInput component here
`
```

Example code.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const SuperInput = styled.input`
  // CSS here
`
```

```
import { Field } from 'formik'
import { SuperInput } from 'styled_components/super_input'

const SomeFormComponent = () => (
  <>
   // How to use here <Field /> that has <SuperInput /> CSS applied?
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to spread or append inside the template literals to get it to work. you can keep the common CSS something like

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components"

const commonCss = css`
  background: red;
`
```

And can use it in your component like this:

```
const Input = styled(Field)`
// CSS goes here
  ${commonCss}
  color: hotpink;
`;

const Input1 = styled(Field)`
  ${commonCss}
  color: lightblue;
`;
```

This should allow you to use the common CSS in various styled components.
For more info, you can read through [css styled component API](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css)

Edit:
Styled components create HOCs. 
After the added superInput definition, I understand what you are trying to do. So your superInput is creating a button with the certain css properties which you are trying to reuse. In that case when you are using Field and trying to extend SuperInput which is a button doesnot make sense. Your Field component is by default a input element(text box), it can be checkbox, radio, file input also.Whatever CSS is written in superInput can be extracted the way I mentioned above and used at multiple places. The way you are trying to do is not the way styled component is designed. That's my understanding

Note : I may be wrong here about whether it is possible or not. But that's what i can say according to my awareness . Anyone Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but then `commonCss` (which is `SuperInput` in my case) is not a standalone `styled-component` component and can't be used as one.

Comment: when we say SuperInput is not a standalone styled-component , what do we mean by that. Could you please show me the definition of SupeIinput ?

Comment: Thanks for the example added. you showed the example usage here but what i am asking is the definition of SuperInput in styled_components/super_input file. Seeing that can only make me understand the problem!!

Comment: Oh, got you. Added.